# C++ compiler optimization for complex equations

Tags: c++

I have some equations that involve multiple operations that I would like to run as fast as possible.  Since the c++ compiler breaks it down in to machine code anyway does it matter if I break it up to multiple lines like

```
A=4*B+4*C;
D=3*E/F;
G=A*D;
```

vs

```
G=12*E*(B+C)/F;
```

My need is more complex than this but the i think it conveys the idea.  Also if this is in a function that gets called is in a loop, does defining double A, D cost CPU time vs putting it in as a class variable?

Comment: Don't worry about it. If you're compiling with optimizations, I'd be surprised if it didn't create the same assembly code anyway.

Comment: The answer to all these kinds of optimization questions is "measure and find out yourself". That being said, compiler writers have thought about this a lot more thoroughly than you think they do, so I would be surprised if there was a measureable difference (assuming that these are simply arithmetic operations). Code for readability first.

Comment: If you look up the manual of the compiler of your choice such optimizations should be listed and explained there. It's worth to take a look.

Comment: Usually, if you're at the point where the compiler won't optimize it enough, you'll be writing the assembly yourself. You can always inspect the assembly yourself. Micro optimizations like this almost always have zilch effect on the final runtime.

Comment: You shouldn't worry about this the compiler probably don't care about transition variables. But if this part is critical in your program you could try to write the assembly yourself (but i don't know if you will be more efficient than g++)

That being said here is the options of gcc compiler : https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Answer (score 1):

Using a modern compiler, Clang/Gcc/VC++/Intel, it won't really matter, the best thing you should do is worry about how readable your code will be and turn on optimizations, compiler designers are well aware of issues like these and design their compilers to (for the most part) optimize according.

If I were to say which would be slower I would assume the first way since there would be 3 mov instructions, I could be wrong. but this isn't something you should worry about too much.

Answer (score 0):

If these variables are integers, that second code fragment is not a valid optimization of the first. For `B=1`, `C=1`, `E=1`, `F=6`, you have:

```
A=4*B+4*C; // 8
D=3*E/F; // 0
G=A*D; // 0
```

and

```
G=12*E*(B+C)/F; // 4
```

If floating point, then it really depends on what compiler, what compiler options, and what cpu you have.